# how to get object reference of multiple input elements in HTML5 using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML5 page containing input `textbox` elements with same ID.

How do I get object reference of each of the input `textbox` using jQuery.

I dont want to use the .each option to do this function.  Can this be done using a count loop?

Comment: Hi Mike, Show us the html5 code?

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**... use a class instead of id for selecting multiple elements

Comment: how to get the nth textbox object reference?

Comment: I want do something like this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#user").get[0].val("Peter");
        $("#user").get[1].val("Munroe");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Name: <input type="text" id="user"></p>
<p>Name: <input type="text" id="user"></p>

<button>Set the value of the input field</button>

</body>
</html>

Comment: what you wanna do exactly?? get the values of each textbox?? for what reasons you want to avoid .each??

Comment: Guru, the values for these textbox come from a json array, the values of which I will be getting using a counter value.. so want to use the same approach for getting the object reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all input elements and use a for loop on the elements:

```
var inputs = $('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
```

Comment: thanks Konstantin, I was able to modify it a bit to get specific textbox element using the following change in your code.  Actually the code that I shared has just 2 textboxes, but I actually have a lot of such textbox and dropdown fields.
var inputs = $('input#user')